# Pretty URLs with .htaccess rewrite engine

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hej,

I'm trying to achieve a pretty urls for my site with rewrite engine. The goal is this - mysite.dk/da, mysite.dk/da/success and mysite.dk/da#scroll.

So far my htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
DirectoryIndex /index.php
```

I tried to implement this

```
RewriteRule ^da$ da.php [L]
RewriteRule ^da/success$ success.php [L]
```

but that didn't really help:/
Thanks

Comment: da = dansk = danish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it like this:

```bash
# Default index
DirectoryIndex index.php

# disable directory listing and MultiViews
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes

# disable automatic addition of trailing / after a directory
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteEngine on

# add .php extension 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: That doesn't work the desired way either :/

Comment: My apology. Well, I need to append .php to the landing page da.php as well as /da/succes.php (in danish is success with a single s, I'm not making this spelling over and over xD) and avoiding those was kinda the point of this struggle. Would you have some further advice?:)

Comment: Because I wanted to have a pretty url without the .php appending...just like mysite.dk/home instead of having mysite.dk/home.php. Can you see? : )

Comment: ok in which directory this .htaccess is located and what is `DOCUMENT_ROOT` value?

Comment: .htaccess is on the very top of all directories, indexes, and other stuff like robots.txt, etc. I searched all my Apache configuration files and I did not find anything related to DOCUMENT_ROOT and I don't have any configuration file containing this I believe :(

Comment: ok can you try my updated answer now

Comment: Wonderful, that's almost perfect! Right now I still need to append .php after succes to make it work so it's like that - mysite.dk/da/succes.php it would be brilliant if we could make it work as mysite.dk/da/succes :)) I assume it is this line of code "RewriteRule ^da/succes$ succes.php [L,NC]". I'm curious what the standard is for this, if there were more pages inside the "da" repository how to make them all work like that without making a rewrite rule for every single one of them?:) thank you so far

Comment: Actually you don't need any rule under `# Specific rewrites` line. I have removed it. Can you retest with my updated .htaccess code

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the pretty URLs you want, modify your `.htaccess` file like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Specific rewrites
RewriteRule ^da$ da.php [L]
RewriteRule ^da/success$ success.php [L]

# General rewrites
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]

# Default index
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

1. Place specific rules for `da` and `da/success` at the top so they take precedence.
2. Use `[L]` to stop further rewriting for these specific cases.
3. General rules follow after the specific ones.

Comment: well but then it guides me into the repository "da" and to enter the single page "da.php" I have to append .php to make it work, right? I noticed that these rules are kinda crossing so I'm still confused how to make it work but it seems to be some kind of standard of every multilingual site so it shouldn't be that difficult...

Comment: The rule `RewriteRule ^da$ da.php [L]` will rewrite URLs ending with `/da` to `da.php.` The `[L]` flag will stop further rewriting, so you won't face the problem of appending `.php` to this particular URL.

Comment: Okay I see that but from some reason I still have this directory content list right now when I enter the url mysite.dk/da and to access the desired site I still need to append .php like mysite.dk/da.php :// idk how to post screenshots in comments